# Java Jackson deserialize an object containing a list of object with/without custom Deserializer?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I've got a JSON input like this

```
{
"slices": [{
        "slice": {
            "boundedBy": {
                "Envelope": {
                    "axisLabels": "Lat Long ansi",
                    "lowerCorner": "-44.975 111.975 \"2003-01-01T00:00:00+00:00\"",
                    "upperCorner": "-8.975 155.975 \"2003-01-01T00:00:00+00:00\"",
                    "srsDimension": 3
                }
            },
            "fileReferenceHistory": "/home/rasdaman/rasdaman_community/rasdaman/systemtest/testcases_services/test_all_wcst_import/testdata/wcs_local_metadata_tiff_no_specify_bands/GlobLAI-20030101-20030110-H01V06-1.0_MERIS-FR-LAI-HA.tiff",
            "local_metadata_key": "value_1"
        }
    },
    {
        "slice": {
            "boundedBy": {
                "Envelope": {
                    "axisLabels": "Lat Long ansi",
                    "lowerCorner": "-44.975 111.975 \"2003-10-01T00:00:00+00:00\"",
                    "upperCorner": "-8.975 155.975 \"2003-10-01T00:00:00+00:00\"",
                    "srsDimension": 3
                }
            },
            "fileReferenceHistory": "/home/rasdaman/rasdaman_community/rasdaman/systemtest/testcases_services/test_all_wcst_import/testdata/wcs_local_metadata_tiff_no_specify_bands/GlobLAI-20031001-20031010-H00V10-1.0_MERIS-FR-LAI-HA.tiff",
            "local_metadata_key": "value_2"
        }
    }
],
"Title": "Drought code", 
// other keys:values
}
```

with "slices" is an array of "slice" objects. Out of "slices" is any "keys":"values" but it is not the problem.

Then, I have a POJO class

```
public class CoverageMetadata {

       @JsonProperty(value = "slices")
       @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
       private List<LocalMetadata> localMetadataList;

       private Map<String, String> globalMetadataAttributesMap;

       @JsonAnySetter
       public void addKeyValue(String key, String value) {
            this.globalMetadataAttributesMap.put(key, value);
       }

       @JsonAnyGetter
       public Map<String, String> getGlobalAttributesMap() {
            return globalMetadataAttributesMap;
       }

       // other gettters, setters without Jackson annotations
```

}

and a class inside the list:

```
public class LocalMetadata {

    public static final String LOCAL_METADATA_TAG = "slice";

    private Map<String, String> localMetadataAttributesMap;

    private BoundedBy boundedBy;

    @JsonAnySetter
    // NOTE: To map an unknown list of properties, must use this annotation
    public void addKeyValue(String key, String value) {
        this.localMetadataAttributesMap.put(key, value);
    }


    public LocalMetadata() {
        this.localMetadataAttributesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        this.boundedBy = new BoundedBy();
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    // NOTE: to unwrap the "map" from { "map": { "key": "value" } }, only keep { "key": "value" }
    public Map<String, String> getLocalMetadataAttributesMap() {
        return localMetadataAttributesMap;
    }

    public BoundedBy getBoundedBy() {
        return this.boundedBy;
    }

    public void setBoundedBy(BoundedBy boundedBy) {
        this.boundedBy = boundedBy;
    }

    public LocalMetadata(Map<String, String> localMetadataAttributesMap, BoundedBy boundedBy) {
        this.localMetadataAttributesMap = localMetadataAttributesMap;
        this.boundedBy = boundedBy;
    }
}
```

And the basic code to deserialize JSON to object

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
CoveageMetadata coverageMetadata = objectMapper.readValue(metadata, CoverageMetadata.class);
```

When I try to deserialize the JSON input to CoverageMetadata object, I got the error

```
    Cannot deserialize coverage's metadata in XML/JSON by Jackson, error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: {"slices":[{"slice":{"boundedBy":{"Envelope":{"axisLabels":"Lat Long ansi","srsDimension":3,"lowerCorner":"-44.975 111.975 \"2003-01-01T00:00:00+00:00\"","upperCorner":"-8.975 155.975 \"2003-01-01T00:00:00+00:00\""}},"local_metadata_key":"value_1","fileReferenceHistory":"/home/rasdaman/rasdaman_community/rasdaman/systemtest/testcases_services/test_all_wcst_import/testdata/wcs_local_metadata_tiff_no_specify_bands/GlobLAI-20030101-20030110-H01V06-1.0_MERIS-FR-LAI-HA.tiff"}}],"Title":"Drought code"}; line: 1, column: 21] (through reference chain: petascope.core.gml.metadata.model.CoverageMetadata["slices"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->petascope.core.gml.metadata.model.LocalMetadata["slice"]).
```

How can I deserialize this JSON input String to CoverageMetadataObject with each "slice" element will be mapped to a LocalMetadata object?

Comment: `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` are not meant to unwrap an object from `"key": { object }`. Are you able to get rid of that redundant `"slice"` (the array name `"slices"` already states it will contain slices anyway)?

Comment: @Thomas unfortunately, I couldn't do it because I also need to keep it when serializing/deserializing in XML. <slices><slice>...</slice><slice>...</slice></slices>

Comment: Hmm, I'm not that familiar with XML serialization via Jackson but I'd assume that it should be possible to get rid of that "slice" via some annotation (did you try `@JsonUnwrapped`?)

Comment: @Thomas I mean it is an input requirement to have <slice> exist in XML or "slice": {} in JSON, so I couldn't ignore it when serializing/deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is I create another POJO class to hold the "slices" list, in CoverageMetadata class, it will have

```
public class CoverageMetadata {

     private Map<String, String> globalMetadataAttributesMap; 
     @JsonProperty(value = "slices")    
     private LocalMetadata localMetadata;

...
}
```

New POJO class (class LocalMetadata before was renamed to LocalMetadataChild)

```
public class LocalMetadata {

    @JsonProperty(value = "slice")
    // This is the most important thing to avoid duplicate <slices><slices> when serializing in XML.
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<LocalMetadataChild> localMetadataList;

    public LocalMetadata(List<LocalMetadataChild> localMetadataList) {
        this.localMetadataList = localMetadataList;
    }

    public LocalMetadata() {
        this.localMetadataList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<LocalMetadataChild> getLocalMetadataList() {
        return localMetadataList;
    }

    public void setLocalMetadataList(List<LocalMetadataChild> localMetadataList) {
        this.localMetadataList = localMetadataList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yupp, that would be the simplest way to do it. I had the impression you don't want to do that though. If that isn't the case then I'd suggest you go with this solution.